# Как задвинуть изображение за границы экрана страницы?

Tags: html, css

Нужно поставить изображение по центру, но не получается, потому что картинка бабочки достигает границы экрана, а нужно затолкнуть за эту границу[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Сайт</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">

    <script type="text/javascript">
        (function() {
            var preload = document.getElementById("preloader");
            var loading = 0;
            var id = setInterval(frame, 64);

        function frame() {
            if (loading == 100) {
        clearInterval(id);
            } else {
            loading = loading + 1;
            if (loading == 90) {
          preload.style.opacity = "0";
        }
      }
    }
  })();
</script>

</head>
<body src="pictures/foner.png">
    <li id="text"><a href="">Портфолио</a></li>
    <li id="text"><a href="">Портфолио</a></li>
    <li id="text"><a href="">Портфолио</a></li>

    <img id="logo" src="pictures/logotip.png">
    <img id="fone" src="pictures/fone.png" alt="">
    <img id="foner" src="pictures/fone.png" alt="">
    <img id="fon" src="pictures/fon.png" alt="">


</body>
</html>
```

```
#text {
    list-style-type: none;
    display: inline;
    margin-left: 25px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-family: Comic Sans MS, Comic Sans;
    margin-top: 50px;

}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: grey;
    transition: 2s;
}

a:hover {
    color: black;
    transition: 2s;
}

#logo {
    width: 150px;
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

#fon {
    width: 1800px;
    margin-top: 360px;
    position: relative;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    margin-right: 3000px;
}

#fone {
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 50px;
    background-size: 100%;
}

#foner {
    transform: rotate(180deg);
    margin-top: 540px;
    position: absolute;
}

body {
    background-color: purple;
}
```

Comment: `overflow-x: hidden;` элементу с изображением (то есть не самому `<img>`, а родительскому).

Comment: А как код должен  выглядеть? Просто добавить эту строчку кода в #fon или как?

Comment: Это просто стиль, не код. Добавить его надо в css-стили того элемента, который является родительским по отношению `<img>` - и тогда изображение будет "задвинуто за границы". А вот для центрирования элементов, есть огромное количество способов для разных ситуаций (и по скриншоту, ситуация не ясна => нужный способ не выбрать). Добавь в вопрос [repro] со своей разметкой и стилями, иначе вопрос закроют голосованием.

Comment: Я добавил код html и css, куда впихнуть это?)

Comment: Сейчас надо не впихнуть что-то, а поместить в вопрос [repro] вместо копирования целиком всей разметки страницы - и если от добавления хорошего примера этот вопрос станет достаточно конкретным, то и ответы на него появятся. А сейчас, в вопросе есть только нерабочий копипаст... разбираться в нем (или переписывать его с нуля), желающие вряд ли найдутся.

Comment: Этот сайт все же является вопросным, а не репетиторским (тут не обучают, а отвечают), и это конечно же не сервис "сделайте мне" - поэтому, требуется понимание хотя бы базовой теории... оно нужно и для того чтобы вопрос задать предметно/конкретно, и для того чтобы понять последующие ответы. Учебные материалы есть (например) на MDN: по [HTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTML), по [CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS), и по [прочим веб-технологиям](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web) тоже.